# change aspect ratio of svg in HTML

Tags: html, css, svg

Using HTML and CSS, how do you change the size of an SVG *(using an `<img />` tag to get svg file)* **WITHOUT** keeping the aspect ratio?

Comment: No, i am using an img element, not an svg element @user1721135

Comment: still you can edit the original svg file

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just add `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the `<svg>` root element. Or if you want you can override it when linking to the img, like in [this example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/reference-img-multi-view.html), by using a link like this:

```
<img src="your.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))" />
```

For a live example, try [this](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/images/svglogo.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))) and resize the browser window.

Comment: if you have a `<svg>` element and an image inside it, the `preserveAspectRatio="none"` applied on the root svg element won't do it. To  make it work, apply the attribute on the image element, see [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/wp12wz3L/1/)

Comment: @AdiFatol well, pAR on the root will still apply to the entire svg document/fragment, see https://jsfiddle.net/1xwvdf4L/ (but I really think this is a tangent to the original question).

Comment: Wow great... does it mean you can overwrite properties inside the svg by adding something behind a `#` in the url ??

Is this behavior somewhere deeper explained, or is that a kind of dirty hack?

In my case I have a svg as data uri, would like to know if there is a way to use this even vor data-urls

Answer (score 1):

This finally has direct support in CSS with [aspect-ratio CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio)

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

so you can set any aspect ratio but specifically for SVG

```
img svg {
    /* aspect-ratio: attr(width) / attr(height); */
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
}
```